# Distribution of liquid among different capacity cans

Tags: arithmetic

There are three cans A,B,C. The capacities of A,B and C are 6 liters, 10 liters and 16 liters respectively. Can C contains 16 liters of milk. The milk has to be divided in them using these three cans only.

Now consider the following statements:

1. It is possible to have 6 liters of milk each in can A and can B.
2. It is possible to have 8 liters of milk each in can B and can C.

Which of the statements given above is/are correct ?

1. 1 only
2. 2 only
3. Both 1 and 2
4. Neither 1 nor 2

As I solved the answer is coming :4. Neither 1 nor 2

but the correct answer given somewhere as : 3.Both 1 and 2

I'm not getting which option is true and how ?

Comment: Option 1 is clearly true, so option 4 is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is clearly true.
Pour from C to A: 6 - 0 - 10.
Pour from A to B: 0 - 6 - 10.
Pour from C to A: 6 - 6 - 4 .

Option 2 requires some work.

> Pour from C to B: 0 - 10 - 6.
>  Pour from B to A: 6 - 4 - 6.
>  Pour from A to C : 0 - 4 - 12.
>  Pour from B to A: 4 - 0 - 12.
> Pour from C to B: 4 - 10 - 2.
> Pout from B to A: 6 - 8 - 2.
> Pour from A to C: 0 - 8 - 8 .

Answer (score 1):

Answer for 2nd statement -
[6-6-4] (from statement 1)

Step-1 = [2-10-4]

Step 2 = [2-0-14]

Step 3 = [0-2-14]

Step 4 = [6-2-8]

Step 5 = [0-8-8]